# ip address to connect to remote database

Tags: mysql, ip-address, ipv4

I understand that there's local ipv4 address that we can get from **ipconfig** in commandline and the public ip address that we get from google. If I am trying to establish connection to a remote database, which has to grant access according to the ip address, which address should I give, so that access can be granted in the future?

Comment: You should speak with the people running the database about this. They'll be the ones to give you the correct answer.

Comment: They just asked me to provide the ip address, so that they can grant access. I am not sure which ip address to give.@music2myear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, the vital term you used is *remote*. If you are connecting to a *remote database server*—that is, one which is outside your immediate LAN, that database server will see your public IP address.

I imagine the database administrator is asking for your IP address to whitelist it. This further confirms my suspicion that they expect your public IP.

Use any of the hundreds of websites that show your public IP address, such as [this one](https://whatismyipaddress.com), and provide that.

**NOTE**: Most residential IPv4 addresses are dynamic addresses. As such, your address may soon change.

Comment: This is exactly my doubt. I am connected by wifi and my ipv4 in ipconfig is local (I believe), but the one given by my isp is dynamic. So, how can I make this work?

Comment: That's tough. There isn't really a way to work around it. Depending on your ISP, you may be able to pay them an additional monthly sum to have a static (unchanging) public IP. Really, it's more of the database administrator's problem. They should set up another solution (such as a VPN)—whitelisting by public IP is an archaic solution.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this @Joseph. I am going ahead with the public ip for now